# Rails 7: Turbo calls not existing create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem. In my Rails app, I am trying to load a list of data using given select-option elements. When I hit submit, I am getting an error that the `create` method doesn't exist in my controller (which is true). I am new with this turbo-rails package, but this is what I got so far:

### index.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'users/main', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="users">
                    <div class="filters">
                        <form action="/users" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
                            <%= render partial: "shared/select", locals: {
                                placeholder: 'Gender', 
                                width: '90px', 
                                options: $genders,
                                classes: 'filter',
                                name: 'gender'
                            } %>

                            <button type="submit">submit</button>

                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div id="user-data-list">
                        <%= render partial: "users/user_list", locals: {
                            users: @users
                        } %>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

### users.controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :require_user

    USERS_PER_PAGE = 15

    def index
        @users = User.limit(USERS_PER_PAGE).order(:creation_date).reverse_order
    end


    def load
        gender = if params[:gender] then params[:gender] else '' end

        @users = User.limit(USERS_PER_PAGE).where(
            "gender LIKE ?", "%" + gender + "%"
        ).order(:creation_date).reverse_order

        respond_to do |format|
            format.turbo_stream
            format.html { redirect_to users_url() }
        end
    end
end
```

### load.turbo_stream.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace "user-data-list" do %>
    <%= render partial: "users/user_list", locals: {
        users: @users
    } %>
<% end %>
```

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # System check
  get '/health', to: 'application#health'

  get '/users' => "users#index"
  post '/users' => "users#load"
  resources :users

  post '/login' => 'auth#login'
  get '/logout' => 'auth#logout'
end
```

### _select.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'components/select', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select
            style="<%= 'width: ' + width + ';' if width %>"
            <% if defined?(id) %>
                id="<%= id %>"
            <% end %>
            <% if defined?(classes) %>
                class="<%= classes %>"
            <% end %>
            <% if defined?(name) %>
                name="<%= name %>"
            <% end %>
            <% if defined?(required) %>
                required
            <% end %>
        >
            <option 
                value="" 
                disabled 
                selected 
                hidden
            >
                <%= placeholder %>
            </option>

            <% options.each do |option| %>
                <option><%= option %></option>
            <% end %>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I run this code and hit the submit button I get the following error:
[image]

I don't have a `create` method in my controller, because there is no possible option to create a user. I have a custom `load` method, and I can't seem to figure out why it is trying to call the `create` method. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes have priority in the order they are declared.

`resources :users` already declares a `POST /users` route. While you could fix it by moving your strange route up you don't actually even need this in the first place.

What you're doing looks like you're simply adding a bunch of filters to a resource. You can do that by just sending a GET request to the collection path (the index) and having it use the optional query string parameters to apply conditions.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # System check
  get '/health', to: 'application#health'

  # Only declare the routes you're actually using!
  resources :users, only: [:index]

  post '/login' => 'auth#login'
  get '/logout' => 'auth#logout'
end
```

```
<%= form_with(url: users_path, method: :get,  data: { turbo_frame: "user-data-list" }) do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/select", locals: {
                                placeholder: 'Gender', 
                                width: '90px', 
                                # why is this a global?
                                options: $genders,
                                classes: 'filter',
                                name: 'gender',
                                form: form # pass the form builder along
                            } %> 

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```
# /app/users/index.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.replace "user-data-list" do %>
    <%= render partial: "users/user_list", locals: {
        users: @users
    } %>
<% end %>
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  USERS_PER_PAGE = 15

  def index
    @users = User.limit(USERS_PER_PAGE)
                 .order(:creation_date: :desc)
    if params[:gender] 
      # and why is this pattern matching? 
      @users.where("gender LIKE ?", "%#{gender}%")
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

Conceptually performing a search, adding pagination or any other kinds of filters via query strings parameters are idempotent actions as its not creating or altering anything and the resource will look the same for any visitor using the same URI (in theory at least).

You should thus use GET and not POST which lets the request be saved in the browsers history - be cached, and be directly linkable.

Comment: Could you also provide an example of the partial `shared/select` with the form builder implemented, because I am still doing something wrong there? Besides the partial, I can already see a full page reload when hitting the submit button. This should not be the case right?

Comment: No, actually I can't. That partial is one of your crazy schemes and I have no idea what it renders. It was pretty hard to even reverse engineer even this much out of the question.

Comment: Sorry, Shall I provide my partial? I'm pretty new with the entire rails stuff, so I am not understanding every subject your saying, for instance the `form builder`. I don't actually know what to do with the `form` variable inside my partial

Comment: If I can give you a word of advice - forget about about Turbo for now. You're not there yet. Just focus on building a classical Rails app and learning the conventions.

Comment: Okay I will read the https://guides.rubyonrails.org/. I figured out the partial with the form now, because I can see in the URI that my `?gender=man`, but I am still wondering why my entire page is reloading. The whole purpose of turbo was to not reload the page, while still changing the data on the screen or???

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. Check the logs if its requesting a turbo stream instead of HTML.

Comment: There are no errors in the logs or console. It looks like it is doing a full GET request. All elements in the view are being reloaded